# Detecting two consecutive "Proper Case" words in a string using R

Tags: r, text-mining

I've been scratching my head about this one for a while now. I'm attempting to do some text mining in R, and am looking to try and classify names, places and organisations which are made up of multiple words. For the purposes of this task I'm only looking at consecutive words in the string which begin with capital letters.

Example String:

```
origString <- 'The current president of the United States is Donald Trump'
```

Is there a way of finding words starting with a capital letter within this string and grouping them together to return something like this?

```
newString <- 'The current president of the UnitedStates is DonaldTrump'
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution would work well for groups of two words at a time:

```
origString <- 'The current president of the United States is Donald Trump'
gsub('([A-Z]\\w*?)\\s+([A-Z]\\w*)', '\\1\\2', origString)
```

**Output:**

```
[1] "The current president of the UnitedStates is DonaldTrump"
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

**Update:**

Following is a script which should work for any number of clustered capitalized words.  It required a workaround/hack because the regex flavor which `gsub()` uses, even in Perl mode, does not support variable length lookbehinds.  The strategy here is instead to selectively remove the *whitespace* in between all capitalized words which appear in groups of two or more.

```
origString <- 'The current president of the United States Donald Trump'
temp <- gsub('([A-Z]\\w*)', '\\1\\$MARK\\$', origString)
output <- gsub('(?<=\\$MARK\\$)\\s+(?=[A-Z])', '', temp, perl=TRUE)
output <- gsub('\\$MARK\\$', '', output)
output

[1] "The current president of the UnitedStatesDonaldTrump"
```

## Demo

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Reckon it's time to brush up on the ol' regex.

Comment: @ReubenKandiah The problem becomes harder if you want to support groups of 3, 4, ... Do you need this as well?

Comment: I can certainly imagine instances where I would - for example the phrase "World Duty Free is the biggest UK operator" would ideally be reduced to "WorldDutyFree is the biggest UK operator".

Comment: @ReubenKandiah Tricky problem.  I gave you a solution which works for any number of grouped capitalized words.  A bit ugly, but `gsub` only supports fixed width lookbehinds, so I had to get creative.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive function that will collapse any number of consecutive capitalised words...

```
collapseCaps <- function(text) {
  result <- gsub('([A-Z]\\w*)\\s+([A-Z]\\w*)', '\\1\\2', text)
  if(result!=text) {
    text <- result
    result <- Recall(text) #calling the function from within itself
  }
  return(result)
}

collapseCaps('The current president of the United States is President Donald J Trump')

[1] "The current president of the UnitedStates is PresidentDonaldJTrump"
```